# Laravel 7. I have missing files from /assets/vendor/. Where can they be?

Tags: laravel

I need help with the following problem:

I inherited a Laravel 7 project from unknown programmers. The project code was in git. After copying to the server, I did **composer install** and **npm install**. The site started up, but a lot of errors appeared in console, reporting missing css and js files in */assets/vendor/*. These files are indeed missing. At first I thought that I needed to publish **php artisan vendor:publish**, but after doing it, the files did not appear.

Does anyone have any suggestions how I could get these files?

UPD: Also I ran **npm run dev** and checked the mixer settings, nothing special there.

The code uses files like this:

```
<script src="{{ url('public/assets/vendor/bootstrap-datepicker/dist/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js') }}"></script>
```

Comment: check the artisan commands that are available, perhaps there is some third party *:publish commands, you could try to do `php artisan :publish` to see all commands that end with publish. Did you run `npm run dev` ? it's also possible that some files get copied there on build

Comment: Looked through `php artisan list`. It looks like `vendor:publish` is only one command related to publishing. I ran `npm run dev` and checked the mixer settings, nothing special there.

Comment: Any package name on the missing files ? Perhaps those files belong to a removed package. Worst case scenario those files have been uploaded by hand

Comment: For example: http://127.0.0.1:8000/public/assets/vendor/jquery-sparkline/jquery.sparkline.js

Comment: run npm run watch.... laravel uses webpack, mix to combine frontend assests.

Comment: any chance this vendor folder was symlinked to node_modules ? Are those packages in your package.json ?

Comment: Unfortunately, there are even chances that this folder was symlinked to the Martians. The project is in a terrible state.

Comment: Perhaps those folders came with the theme used, if it's the case and you know the theme name, you can perhaps find it online

Comment: Hmm, interesting guess. Thanks, I'll look for traces of any theme in the project.